Python requests module with multithread
Currently, I am developing the astrophotometric software for multiple telescopes. For this, I constructed a mother computer connected with multiple telescopes and these telescopes can be controlled by HTTP protocol.
For synchronized operation, I am trying to control these multiple telescopes simultaneously with multithreading.
However, when I retrieve image data (110MB for each, ~1.2GB for total) from multiple telescopes (10 telescopes), the data transfer speed is much slower than I expected. For seamless operation, we have 10G connection with the mother computer, and 1G connection with 10 telescopes. I expected ~9Gbps data transfer speed when 10 telescopes transfer the data simultaneously, but only 1.5Gbps achieved.
For simple test, I extracted the part of the code and check the time consumption.
import requests
import time
from astropy.time import Time
def request_imagearray(cam):
    client_trans_id = 1
    client_id = 1
    attribute = 'imagearray'

    url = f"{cam.device.base_url}/{attribute}"
    hdrs = {'accept' : 'application/imagebytes'}
    # Make Host: header safe for IPv6
    if(cam.device.address.startswith('[') and cam.device.address.startswith('[::1]')):
        hdrs['Host'] = f'{cam.device.address.split("%")[0]}]'
    pdata = {
            "ClientTransactionID": f"{client_trans_id}",
            "ClientID": f"{client_id}" 
            }         

    print('START:',Time.now(), cam.device.address)
    start = time.time()
    response = requests.request("GET","%s/%s" % (cam.device.base_url, attribute), params=pdata, headers=hdrs, verify = False)

    print('consumed time:', time.time() - start, cam.device.address)
# %%

unitnumlist = [1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
camlist = []
for unitnum in unitnumlist:
    #camlist.append(mainCamera(unitnum))
    Thread(target = request_imagearray, kwargs = dict(cam = mainCamera(unitnum))).start()
#%% 

and the output is
START: 2024-04-15 07:49:59.067946 10.0.106.6:11111
START: 2024-04-15 07:49:59.382973 10.0.106.7:11112
START: 2024-04-15 07:49:59.541495 10.0.106.8:11113
START: 2024-04-15 07:49:59.647055 10.0.106.10:11111
START: 2024-04-15 07:49:59.788433 10.0.106.11:11111
START: 2024-04-15 07:49:59.897876 10.0.106.12:11111
START: 2024-04-15 07:50:00.009254 10.0.106.13:11111
START: 2024-04-15 07:50:00.157893 10.0.106.14:11111
START: 2024-04-15 07:50:00.347704 10.0.106.16:11111
START: 2024-04-15 07:50:00.544626 10.0.106.9:11111
consumed time: 5.96204686164856 10.0.106.6:11111
consumed time: 7.304373502731323 10.0.106.7:11112
consumed time: 7.58618688583374 10.0.106.8:11113
consumed time: 7.617574453353882 10.0.106.10:11111
consumed time: 7.678117990493774 10.0.106.11:11111
consumed time: 7.76300311088562 10.0.106.12:11111
consumed time: 7.636215925216675 10.0.106.14:11111
consumed time: 7.785021066665649 10.0.106.13:11111
consumed time: 7.338518857955933 10.0.106.9:11111
consumed time: 11.309057235717773 10.0.106.16:11111

The comsumed time is much longer than I expected. I expected ~3sec for all data transferred. It seems that multithreads starts to request "request.get" at the same time, but all the data is not transferred at the same time.

What is the elapsed time for a single synchronous GET (e.g., to 10.0.106.6:11111). Also, it may be your network interface that's causing a bottleneck. You could try using fewer concurrent threads to obviate that potential issue

Do you have more details on your mother computer hardware / on the hardware used between the mother computer and the telescopes ? Also, when you use a single connection, what is the transfer speed ?  Is it indeed 1 Gb/s as expected ?

Elapsed dtime for a single "GET" is ~2 seconds.

For simplicity of the question, I didn't write the hardware for each telescope. For each telescope, there is "telescope computer".
Mother computer specification : Dell workstation 7920 Tower
-CPU: Intel Xeon Gold 6240R
-RAM: 2x64GB DDR4 2933
-SSD: M.2 4TB PCIe NVMe Class 40 Solid State Drive
-HDD: '4EA x 3.5" 12TB 7,200rpm SATA AG-Enterprise Hard Drive
-NIC: Intel Ethernet 10G 2P X710 T2L-t NIC
Telescope computer specification
-CPU: i5-13600K
-RAM: DDR5 PC5-44800 [16GB] * 2
-M/B: B760-A

All telescope computer has 1G connection, while mother computer has 10G connection. When using "iperf3" for checking the network speed of all units, the network speed is proportional to the number of connection with teelescope computer. (For example, when 3 connection with telescope computers and mother computer, ~3Gbps)

Use requests.Session to open one connection instead of reopen it every request.request.
I would also suggest using ThreadPoolExecutor for a more convenient threading interface
import time
from concurrent.futures.thread import ThreadPoolExecutor
from itertools import repeat

import requests
from astropy.time import Time


def request_imagearray(cam, _session):
    client_trans_id = 1
    client_id = 1
    attribute = 'imagearray'

    url = f"{cam.device.base_url}/{attribute}"
    hdrs = {'accept': 'application/imagebytes'}
    # Make Host: header safe for IPv6
    if cam.device.address.startswith('[') and cam.device.address.startswith('[::1]'):
        hdrs['Host'] = f'{cam.device.address.split("%")[0]}]'
    pdata = {
        "ClientTransactionID": f"{client_trans_id}",
        "ClientID": f"{client_id}"
    }

    print('START:', Time.now(), cam.device.address)
    start = time.time()
    response = _session.get(url, params=pdata, headers=hdrs, verify=False)
    print('consumed time:', time.time() - start, cam.device.address)


unitnumlist = [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
camlist = [mainCamera(unitnum) for unitnum in unitnumlist]
with requests.Session() as session:
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=max(len(unitnumlist), 1)) as executor:
        results = executor.map(request_imagearray, camlist, repeat(session))

The assignment to results is in case request_imagearray returns something.

requests.Session may not be thread safe. See this discussion

@SIGHUP this is an old post, sessions are using urllib3’s connection pooling now which is thread safe (I'm also using it that way myself with thousands of requests and never had an issue).

Thank you for that. Very interesting. One other comment though... Is there value  in using a Session when the URL domains are all different?

requests.Session() just open a connection, it doesn't have a fixed url. If you drill down to the request source code you will see the exact same code.

But the connections are to different domains so you'd have a pool of connections to 10.0.106.6, 10.0.106.7 etc

@SIGHUP It doesn't matter, every get is stand alone. See the source code for the request function.

Thanks for your friendly answer!
But, even though I used pre-defined 'Session', there seems no difference in elapsed time. The amount time for establishing a new connection may not significantly affect the elapsed time.
